# /t is not recognized as an internal or external command. C# batch script

Tags: c#, windows, batch-file

I am trying to run a batch file in c# from the project itself. Whenever I run it though, I get the error:

```
/t is not recognized as an internal or external command.
```

**EDIT: This batch file runs perfectly fine outside of my C# project.**

I would like to run batch files from within my application without needing the batch files themselves. I know that would probably be preferable, but I can't figure out how to run batch files from the working directory of my project, so this is the next best thing for me.

Here is my code(note, I have System.diagnostics added in my project):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string batTest;
            batTest = @"
                @ECHO CHEF WORKSTATION FIX   
                @ECHO VERSION: 1.00.041316
                @ECHO.
                @ECHO THIS WILL DELETE THE CONTENTS OF 'c:\chef'
                @ECHO.
                @ECHO ARE YOU SURE YOU WANT TO CONTINUE ?
                @PAUSE
                @set folder='C:\chef'
                @IF EXIST '%folder%' (
                    cd /d %folder%
                    for /F 'delims=' %%i in ('dir /b') do (rmdir '%%i' /s/q || del '%%i' /s)
                )
                @ECHO.
                @ECHO DELETED CONTENTS OF 'c:\chef'
                @PAUSE
                @ECHO.
                @ECHO UPDATE GROUP POLICIES ?
                @PAUSE
                @GPUPDATE /FORCE
                @ECHO.
                @ECHO REBOOT COMPUTER TO COMPLETE FIX ?
                @PAUSE
                @shutdown.exe /r /t 00
            ";
            Process.Start(@"cmd.exe", batTest);
        }
```

Comment: This shouldn't be tagged c#.  It's just about the batch file.  c# is superfluous.

Comment: @roryap why not.. `Process.Start` is clearly valid C# code / function call within the current context.. personally I would try to put the contents into a batch file vs building a string and try to execute the batch file via Porcess.Start

Comment: Because the error relates to `/t`, in the batch file.  If you take the batch file out of the c# code and run it, it would have the same problem.  You could run it on its own (by double-clicking it), from VBS, VB.NET, hell, another batch file.  c# is superfluous information.

Comment: yeah.. not sure what you mean? This is clearly focused around the functionality OF c#? 

@MethodMan I would love to do this, but I will be running this application off of a USB drive and can't target a file path as the drive letter will change dependent on the computer it's plugged into. I have tried to target the working directory, but I can't get it to work correctly, so this is why I went this route. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Try this: `Process.Start(@"cmd.exe", "/c " + batTest);` to get it to execute the command in your string.

Comment: @roryap It actually doesn't have the same problem. Create the batch file and run it yourself. I have no issues with the batch file outside of my C# Project.

Comment: @Quantic, thank you. This actually no longer spits out the error message and I can see the first line which is "CHEF WORKSTATION FIX", but it closes immediately after. I think I'm on the right track with this though, I will research more and keep trying.

Comment: There may be a better way, but it appears that you need to put `&&` after every line to get it to run each command as a passed in string.

Comment: @Quantic, thanks but that didn't work. I think the moral of the story is this is just a poor method for achieving what I want to do. Thanks for trying, I appreciate the help.

Comment: `cmd /c rd /s c:\chief & md c:\chief & shutdown /r /t 0` seems simple. I'm not going to risk a reboot are you sure `00` works? Does the error occur with just `0`?

Comment: Are you sure the line breaks are coming in as part of your string?  Try it with a newline character at the end of each line:  `batTest = @" @ECHO CHEF WORKSTATION FIX" + Environment.NewLine + "@ECHO VERSION: 1.00.041316" + Environment.NewLine + "blah blah` etc.

Comment: @Noodles thanks for the reply. yes, 00 works. The script itself runs fine outside of my C# project, which is what I seriously don't understand. It's killing me! I did take your advice and try it with just 0, and it still crashes after one line.

Comment: @WesLarson thanks Wes. I tried this as well, and I still get it crashing right after the first line of Echo Chef workstation fix. I can see that it did indeed echo the string of text, but it closes immediately. I also tried putting a pause right after this line, and had no luck.

Comment: Might it be easier to write your batch script to a file, then run it, and then delete it at the end?

Comment: @WesLarson, you're absolutely correct. My issue though, is I will be running this application from a USB drive and the batch file will be stored on that USB drive along with the executable for the application. I haven't been able to figure out how to access the batch file from the project folder. I have tried everything, which is why I came to this solution. Which doesn't appear to be a very good solution lol

Comment: Can you write it to the %temp% folder, instead of the local USB drive?

Comment: @WesLarson, sorry wes, this is where my knowledge isn't very strong. I wouldn't know how to do that off the top of my head. I will need to research that first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This little console program (as discussed in the comments) uses the `StreamWriter.WriteLine` method to write the lines of the batch file to a text file in the `%temp%` folder.  It then executes the batch script and then deletes it when finished.

```
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace CreateAndRunBatchFile
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string batTest = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP") +
                @"\batchfile.bat";
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(batTest))
            {                
                sw.WriteLine("@echo off");
                sw.WriteLine("echo Batch program has started...");
                sw.WriteLine("REM Add your lines of batch script code like this");
                sw.WriteLine("pause");
                sw.WriteLine("exit");
            }
            Process.Start(@"cmd.exe ", "/c " + batTest);
            Process.Start(@"cmd.exe ", "/c del " + batTest);
        }
    }
}
```